# Sharepoint 2013 - Display full breadcrumbs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, breadcrumbs

When displaying a document list and browse through it's folders breadcrumbs are shown at the top as displayed in the below image:

[image]

Is it possible to display the full breadcrumbs i.e. 1 -> 2 -> 3 instead of 2 -> 3 only?

Can this be done to a sub site only instead of the whole farm?

Comment: If you don't have any luck here, you might want to try the SharePoint site http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DeanOC Thanks! Posted there too!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 offers its own breadcrumb which is hidden by default. To enable the breadcrumb, we just need to make a small change in master page. 
Find the following snippet in your master page and change the following attributes: 
'Visible' to true 
Remove the style="display: none" from the parent div. 
  [master page code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z42Qv.png)

After making the changes, save the master page. You will now see button in top 
.
 Clicking on expand button will show the default breadcrumb. 
 [default sharepoint breadcrumb image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LMBO.png)

We can then style this in our own way then.